# How to delete a specific line from binary file?

Tags: file

How to delete a specific data from binary file. Please example, thanks :)

Comment: The only way to delete *some* contents of a file is truncate the file and overwrite it with the new, smaller contents. Also, specific *line* from *binary* file?

Comment: 1) This site is not a "write my code for me" site. 2) Without specifying any kind of specific format, how does anyone know what a "line" is in this context.

Comment: O_o Lines is something related to ascii. Lines in binary files are completely coincidental.

Comment: I'm thinking he means `a specific byte sequence`

Comment: you want to delete a  line at a line number or a specific line ?

Comment: Yes I mean `a specific byte sequence`

Comment: Also a newline cannot be trusted in binary file as it has a full rage of 0-255

Comment: @user1069874 : What does this "a specific byte sequence" mean ? or what is it ? can it be mapped to a C/C++ structure ? if nothing then you will have to search and append in a char buffer and finally dump it into another file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binary files have no lines, but to delete any block of data from any file you just need to write the data after this block starting at this block beginning and truncate the tail.

**EDIT**: to delete *specific data* you have to find the data and then read the first paragraph again :)

Answer (score 1):

Binary data could have various types of structure, but not 'lines'.  A priori, I recommend that you use some established library designed for however your data is formatted be it binary XML, Berkeley DB, whatever.